# is there any code statistics tool for python, like counting function lengh in line?

Tags: python, statistics

i want to find out python functions with line length > 80(e.g.)

Any tools to do it?

Further i may need to find which functions are[not] called in a run.

simple is better.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the PEP8 module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) and snakefood (http://furius.ca/snakefood/doc/snakefood-doc.html)

Comment: What does this have to with statistics?

Comment: it seems pep8 does not check function size

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131153/open-source-code-review-tools-mondrian

Answer (score 1):

Try [pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint). It can check a number of coding standards that you configure, including line length.